# Sum Values by conditions for the previous period

Tags: matrix, dax

Please, could you help me with task below?

I have problem with dax calculation for Sum Values by conditions for the previous period in Matrix table.

[Source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGcXx.png)

[Matrix table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfa7c.png)

I have 3 conditions in column "Board".

1. QuartalBoard
2. MonthBoard
3. WeekBoard

For each conditions I need to see calculation of SUM of profit for previous date board period.
Requested result is in the "Matrix table" in the column "Sum of Profit for previous date board period"

Note: Date of Board period is iregullar.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Mar